# How to execute a script remotely in Python using SSH?

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

```
def execute(self,command):
            to_exec = self.transport.open_session()
            to_exec.exec_command(command)
            print 'Command executed'
connection.execute("install.sh")
```

When I check the remote system, I found the script didn't run. Any clue?

Comment: More code, please. Not enough context.

Comment: question is too vague, which ssh wrapper are you using, what is the error, and how did you know that "the script didn't run" instead of "the script runs but with errors".

Comment: I don't know why you want to do that, but if it's for sys administration, you might find [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) useful.

Comment: @charlax [Fabric](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric/1.3.3) is a good suggestion. The author of [Fabric](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric/1.3.3), Jeff Forcier, is also the person who forked Paramiko into the [ssh module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh/1.7.11). My answer addresses the specific question of how to use `ssh` with python, but fabric is an even better way to handle the more general problem that @kevin is likely trying solve.

Answer (score 23):

The code below will do what you want and you can adapt it to your `execute` function:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
host="hostname"
user="username"
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(host, username=user)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('./install.sh')
print "stderr: ", stderr.readlines()
print "pwd: ", stdout.readlines()
```

Note, though, that commands will default to your `$HOME` directory, so you'll either need to have `install.sh` in your `$PATH` or (most likely) you'll need to `cd` to the directory that contains the `install.sh` script.

You can check your default path with:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('getconf PATH')
print "PATH: ", stdout.readlines()
```

However, if it is not in your path you can `cd` and execute the script like this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('(cd /path/to/files; ./install.sh)')
print "stderr: ", stderr.readlines()
print "pwd: ", stdout.readlines()
```

If the script is not in your`$PATH` you'll need to use `./install.sh` instead of `install.sh`, just like you would if you were on the command line.

If you are still having problems after everything above it might also be good to check the permissions of the `install.sh` file, too:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -la install.sh')
print "permissions: ", stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this `install.sh` script is on the SSH server under the ssh's working directory. The SSH Client running the python script  may not have this file.  Is there a means to run a shell script found on the client on the server without copying it over first?

Comment: @jxramos any update on the running script which is on the client and not the remote host?

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=username, password = password)
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()

def run_cmd(cmd):    
    print('='*30)
    print('[CMD]', cmd)
    chan.send(cmd + '\n')
    time.sleep(2)
    buff = ''
    while chan.recv_ready():
        print('Reading buffer')
        resp = chan.recv(9999)
        buff = resp.decode()
        print(resp.decode())

        if 'password' in buff:
            time.sleep(1)
            chan.send(password + '\n')        
        time.sleep(2)

    print('Command was successful: ' + cmd)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: OP is asking how to execute a script remotely in Python, not how to run a command and print out the cmd and response for debugging purposes.

Answer (score -3):

```
subprocess.Popen('ssh thehost install.sh')
```

See the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: and make sure you have ssh keys generated otherwise your program will not be able to ask for the password when executed from the cron for example.

Comment: It is better to use the [ssh module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh/1.7.11) which was designed to make it robust and easy to use the SSH protocol; there is no good reason to use `subprocess` module because not only is it more hassle, but you also cannot rely on the return code from `ssh` because if it returns error code 255 you can't tell if that is what your remote script returned or if that was just `ssh` returning the code due to an error entirely unrelated to the remote script.