# Better way of running a python script remotely

Tags: python, ssh

I have a python script on a remote machine which I want to execute from my local machine. It takes in a few arguments and this is how I would run it if I were to run it on that machine.

```
python python_parallel.py --num=10 --ssh=/home/user1/path/file.txt
```

Currently I have a python code in my local machine which runs the above script:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser.add_option("-n", "--num", type="int", dest="num_spice",help="Enter the number")
parser.add_option("-s", "--ssh", dest="ssh_txt",help="Enter the path to the text file")
num_spice=options.num_spice
ssh_txt=options.ssh_txt

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

os.system('ssh user1@10.100.10.201 python /home/user1/path/python_parallel.py --num=%s --ssh=%s' %(num_spice, ssh_txt) )
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
I tried the solution at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783009/how-to-execute-a-script-remotely-in-python-using-ssh), but it gave me an error "ImportError: No module named ssh"

Comment: The module linked in the answer that you linked seems fine. Since you get an import error you might not have installed the module. Try installing it with `pip` or `easy_install`

Comment: Thanks, after installing the module, now I get another error:



File "python_remote_ssh.py", line 14, in <module>
    client.connect(host, username=user)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/ssh/client.py", line 332, in connect
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/ssh/client.py", line 493, in _auth
ssh.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you look at the [plumbum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumbum) module for doing things like this.

Its a pretty cool and easy way to run local commands and you can do the same with remote commands quite easily (with a context manager).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/)? It's really easy to use.

Comment: does Fabric support Windows? I have to run a python script located on a remote Windows machine..