# How run python script in remote machine with ssh

Tags: python, sockets, ssh

I created a python script, I want to run this script from my machine to multiple clients without installing it in the client. Is there any packages, or library available in python to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run local python script on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320705/how-to-run-local-python-script-on-remote-machine)

Comment: You have to have a Python interpreter available on a machine if you want to run a Python program on it. If Python isn't installed on that machine you will have to build and deploy an executable that incorporates your code, the Python interpreter, and any needed libraries. Look at the module `pyinstaller`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:-

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd_to_execute)
```

And you can go through [this](http://www.paramiko.org/)