# Trigger a python script from a remote machine without SSH

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to trigger a python script which sends out a JSON data response back. Technically I want it to work like a Rest API without creating a Rest API.

How I want to invoke?

```
http://www.123.456.789.012/my_python_script/my_function
```

Hitting this URL should trigger the python script, and run the necessary function (my_function()) and that function would need to send back JSON response. I will be triggering the script from my machine using `Python Requests Module`

Can you please tell me a way on how this can be done???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Make a simple webserver with Flask.

Comment: Flask is the only way? Can I in any way make use of simplehttpserver?

Comment: take a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297189/better-way-of-running-a-python-script-remotely

Comment: @Ckl1314 You can of course use simplehttpserver - or even write your own http server from scratch - but using flask will very probably be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you require a remote function to be executed, then you need a server listening/serving responses to your machine.

One of the simple ways is to use Flask. Check it out here : [Flask Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/) and install using `pip install flask`

Create a file named `app.py` and embed the following code

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/my_function')
def index():
    #CODE THAT RETURNS JSON RESPONSE

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Run the program using `python app.py` and whilst its running you can call it from your machine. Also make sure you set the right Inbound rules for the server to accept the requests.

You can trigger this remotely using,

```
the_machine's_ip _address:5000/my_function
```